# Regular expression matches unwanted strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to fix an issue with a regex replace statement. This is the code:

```
var str1 = "bbb/mobile-main.min.js";
var str2 = "ttt/main.min.js";
var str21 = "mobile-main.min.js";
var str22 = "main.min.js";


var re = new RegExp("main\.min\.js" + "(\\?[0-9a-z]+)?", "g");

var ans1 = str1.replace(re, '$1main.78765.min.js');

var ans2 = str2.replace(re, '$1main.78765.min.js');

var ans21 = str21.replace(re, '$1main.78765.min.js');

var ans22 = str22.replace(re, '$1main.78765.min.js');

console.log("ans1: "+ ans1);

console.log("ans2: "+ ans2);

console.log("ans21: "+ ans21);

console.log("ans22: "+ ans22);
```

The result is:

```
   "ans1: bbb/mobile-main.78765.min.js"
   "ans2: ttt/main.78765.min.js"
   "ans21: mobile-main.78765.min.js"
   "ans22: main.78765.min.js"
```

My desired result is only the second string (str2) to match:

```
"bbb/mobile-main.min.js"

"ttt/main.78765.min.js"

"mobile-main.min.js"

"main.78765.min.js"
```

Here is a [link](http://jsbin.com/luzire/3/edit?js,console) to jsbin

I couldn't find a regular expression statement to match my goal.. 
Thanks!

**Edit**: Jsbin link fixed.

Another limitation: I will not always have something infront of file's name. This should have similar results (only second should match):

```
mobile-main.min.js

mail.min.js
```

**Edit2**
Edited code + JSBin with all conditions

Comment: Why should the 1st string not match? Also, jsbin link doesn't work.

Comment: Try changing the regex to this `"\/main\.min\.js"+"(\\?[0-9a-z]+)?"`, so that it looks for the `/` right next to `main`

Comment: I don't believe you need to escape a forward slash in js (or it prob doesn't matter), it'd be: `.replace(new RegExp("/main\.min\.js"+"(\\?[0-9a-z]+)?","g"), "/main.78765.min.js");` though I'm not sure that's what he's asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var re = new RegExp("(^|/)main\.min\.js" + "(\\?[0-9a-z]+)?", "g");

var ans1 = str1.replace(re, '$1main.78765.min.js'); // bbb/mobile-main.min.js
var ans2 = str2.replace(re, '$1main.78765.min.js'); // ttt/main.78765.min.js
```

[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/lusatitopo/1/edit?js,console)

`(^|/)` makes sure that pattern `main\.min\.js` is replaced only when it is at start or preceded by `/`.

Comment: Thanks, this is close, but it is exactly the opposite from what I needed (I needed the second one to match and be replaced. Plus, I need this to match a case when there is not prefix to file name (mentioned in my edit). Thanks again! BTW: I would love some explanation about it, I am trying to master my regex skills (:

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I wanted. Can you please update the comments & the JSBib (this is the correct solution: http://jsbin.com/luzire/4/edit?js,console), only for future reference (:

Comment: Your answer had been really helpful for me. My final solution was a little bit different, because it had to take care of a situation where the string to be replaced was inside of a longer string. (see http://jsbin.com/luzire/9/edit?js,console). The only thing I do not understand is why using the $1 inside '$1main.785...'. I see that without it the first character is being replaced as well. Huge thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I am using `$1` in replacement string because we are capturing line start or `/` in this group here: `(^|/)` so that needs to be put back in replacement.